# Using Google Play filters to limit your app to 4:3 screens

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to publish an app on Google Play, and set it to be available only to 4:3 tablets.

I found the filter to limit to tablet screens:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

However, I was only available to find the filters used to limit some screen densities, e.g.

```
<supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

and not for aspect ratio.

Is there a way to limit an app to 4:3 screens?

Comment: Did you check that - https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#MaxAspectRatio ?

Comment: "and set it to be available only to 4:3 tablets" -- that's a very limited market. "Is there a way to limit an app to 4:3 screens?" -- not via the manifest.

Comment: It's not my decision. Thanks for the link, Divers.